# Is there a way to call gwt methods from "native" java application

Tags: java, gwt

I have a gwt application where the server implements some Service classes, which are then called by the javascript gwt client using the ServiceAsync interface. That is working fine.

But now I need to call the service methods from a normal Java application(Which don't currently use gwt), running on my Linux Desktop and I wonder if this is possible, without having to write a wrapper on the Server.

Comment: Try to use the browser debugger console and view the network connection tab for the AJAX requests that the GWT web app sends to the server. Then just copy the GET/POST request in your desktop native application.